# Most optically transparent muscle phantom?

Tags: muscles, experimental-design, light, tissue, ultrasound

I am trying to use Schlieren imaging techniques to visualize how a sound wave propagates through muscle tissue.

In the past, when needing to experiment with muscle we would use an agar based muscle phantom but they diffuse light. Might anyone have experience with making tissue phantoms that have similar clarity to something like PDMS for example?